# Undefined method for value when running rspec tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am getting a undefined method for 'value' when running my rspec test. I am trying to get the value column in the Votes table for the respective post instance variable being ran in the rspec test.  Am I calling the value wrong?

**Up_votes function description:**

The function is supposed to add to the array if the value of the vote is 1 and doesn't add it, if it is -1. Once that loop is completed, then it is supposed to sum the total number of votes(up votes) in that array.

**Rspec error:**

```
Failures:

1) Post vote methods #up_votes counts the number of votes with value = 1
 Failure/Error: expect(@post.up_votes ).to eq(3)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `value' for #<Vote::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ff2e1621728>
 # ./app/models/post.rb:29:in `up_votes'
 # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top      (required)>'
```

**Rspec test:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Post do
describe "vote methods" do

before do
  @post = Post.create(title: 'Post title', body: 'Post bodies must be pretty long.')
  3.times { @post.votes.create(value: 1)}
  2.times { @post.votes.create(value: -1)}
end

describe '#up_votes' do
  it "counts the number of votes with value = 1" do
    expect(@post.up_votes ).to eq(3)
  end
end

describe '#down_votes' do
  it "counts the number of votes with values = -1" do
    expect(@post.down_votes ).to eq(2)
  end
end

describe '#points' do
  it "returns the sum of all down and up votes" do
    expect(@post.points ).to eq(1) # 3 - 2
  end
end
end
end
```

**Post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :votes
 has_one :summary
 belongs_to :user #means the post table has the user table's primary key in it
belongs_to :topic
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
default_scope {order('created_at DESC')}

validates :title, length: {minimum: 5},  presence: true
validates :body,  length: {minimum: 20}, presence: true
#validates :topic, presence: true
#validates :user, presence: true


 def markdown_title
  (render_as_markdown).render(self.title).html_safe
 end


 def markdown_body
  (render_as_markdown).render(self.body).html_safe
 end

 def up_votes
  vote_array = []
  sum = 0
  vote_array << @post.votes.value.each do |vote| unless @post.votes.value == -1
  vote_catch = vote_array
 end
 end 
  vote_catch.each do |vote|
  sum += vote
  end 
   sum
end
end
```

**Vote.rb file:**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :post
end
```

**Vote schema**

```
create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "value"
  t.integer  "post_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.value` on a collection of votes, as opposed to on a vote itself. Something like `@post.votes` will return a collection.

Could you do something like this?

```
def up_votes
  votes.where(value: 1).count
end
```

That should grab all of the votes for the instance of Post w/ a value of 1 and return the count.

Comment: The count doesn't get the sum of all of the 1's together right?  Its just counting the how many one's there are correct, not adding them together?

Comment: well in this case, it would be the same as its all 1's.  Never mind.  Thanks Alex I am marking this answer as correct.